# hibernate alternate value

Tags: hibernate

I need your help: is there a way in hibernate to set an alternative value when setting an element. For instance:

the element String columnA is linked to the column labeled ColumnA in the db.
When columnA = 1 then the query must also search for 0 (you can se it has the star char).
In other words, the query must contain select ...... from ... where (columnA = 1 or columnA = 0). can I do it automatically using the find by example?

I hope this is clear.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find by example is not the appropriate strategy in this case. Just use an HQL query or a classical criteria query. Or create a Criteria query mixing an example restriction (with columnA set to null or excluded) with a regular disjunction restriction.